# Can we use redux states in a react component without using {connect}?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I usually import {connect} from react-redux to connect my React component to a Redux store.
Is there any other way to access the redux store from react components without using {connect}?

Answer (score 1):

There is useSelector from [React Redux Hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

> The selector is approximately equivalent to the mapStateToProps argument to connect conceptually. The selector will be called with the entire Redux store state as its only argument. The selector will be run whenever the function component renders (unless its reference hasn't changed since a previous render of the component so that a cached result can be returned by the hook without re-running the selector). useSelector() will also subscribe to the Redux store, and run your selector whenever an action is dispatched.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)
  return <div>{counter}</div>
}
```